# Clicking a state to reveal its counties in Altair chart

Tags: python, altair

I want to be able to click on a state (single or multi selection) and reveal the selected states' counties while still continuing to show the non selected states. I've been able to achieve this by constructing a dataframe where I append a geojson file of the states' shapes to a geojson of the counties' shapes.

```
census_area centroid_lat    centroid_lon    county_fips fips    geometry    geomlist    id  iso_3166_2  lsad    name    state   state_fips  state_only_fips
```

state_fips is present for every tuple, where state_only_fips is only present for the state shapes. I then construct my map with the following code:

```
state_selection = alt.selection_single(empty='none', fields=['properties.state_only_fips'])

alt.Chart(combined_geo).mark_geoshape(stroke='black').encode(
).add_selection(
    state_selection
).transform_filter(
    {'not': state_selection}
).properties(
    width=900,
    height=700
).project("albersUsa")
```

This correctly hides the state shape and shows the underlying counties, but it performs poorly. Instead of rendering all county *and* state shapes and hiding only the state shapes I select, I want the process to look like this:

1. Initialize the chart with only the state shapes showing (denoted by having a state_only_fips value, or a value of 'lsad' == 'State')
2. If a state is clicked, hide the selected state while continuing to show all other states
3. Show the selected state's counties shapes. 
   [Display Selected State's Counties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFwIz.png)

I feel this is possible and would make the chart perform better, but I'm not sure how to construct the geojson file and/or my transform_filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to achieve this by having 2 selections: 1 to check for the selected states and one to check for the selected states' counties. To show the states, I show *only* the shapes that are classified as 'State' and have not yet been clicked on. The selection is on *state_only_fips* which is present for only the state shapes.

```
state_selection = alt.selection_multi(empty='none', fields=['properties.state_only_fips'], clear='dblclick')

{'and' : [('datum[\'properties.lsad\'] == \'State\''), {'not': state_selection}]}
```

I added a second selection on *state_fips*, which is included for every shape. In the state shapes, this holds the same value as *state_only_fips*. This second filter also filters out all shapes not classified as 'State'.

```
county_selection = alt.selection_multi(empty='none', fields=['properties.state_fips'], clear='dblclick')

{'and' : [('datum[\'properties.lsad\'] !== \'State\''), county_selection]}
```

Finally, we combine these two statements with an **or** predicate. The final product looks like this:

```
county_selection = alt.selection_multi(empty='none', fields=['properties.state_fips'], clear='dblclick')
state_selection = alt.selection_multi(empty='none', fields=['properties.state_only_fips'], clear='dblclick')

base_chart = alt.Chart().mark_geoshape(stroke='black').encode(
).add_selection(
    state_selection,
    county_selection
).transform_filter(
    {'or': [{'and' : [('datum[\'properties.lsad\'] == \'State\''), {'not': state_selection}]}
        ,{'and' : [('datum[\'properties.lsad\'] !== \'State\''), county_selection]}]}
).properties(
    width=900,
    height=700
).project("albersUsa")
```

This probably could have been done in a more efficient manner, but it works loads better than it did before.